# How do i run a .jar file on a website?

Tags: html, jar, side-scroller

I recently made a 2D sidescroller and i now want it to be on a website.
The game runs via Canvas or JFrame either one. Prob Canvas hence the code.

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

But i just wanted to know how to a Java Game on a website.

EDIT:
Currently my code:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
```

If i change canvas to Applet

```
private void render() {
    //This is a loop for drawing graphics repeatedly on screen
    BufferStrategy bs = this.**getBufferStrategy**();
    if(bs == null){
        this.**createBufferStrategy**(3);
        return;
}
```

The **Bold** is underlined as red.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Painting a Canvas in an Applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424849/painting-a-canvas-in-an-applet)

Comment: You'll have to wrap your code in an applet.

Comment: @RobertMoskal 
Supposing your idea. How would i wrap my code in an applet?

Comment: Follow the question I posted and learn how to deploy applets.

Comment: I dont understand it very well. Please explain it breifly sir.